# Solution to definite integral

Tags: integration

We all know the following differential equation to be true:
$d(uv) = vdu + udv$. Which implies that 
$$\int d(uv)= \int v du+ \int u dv \implies \\  uv = \int v du+ \int u dv. $$

Does this also mean that the following is true:

$$\int_a^b d(uv)= \int_a^b v du+ \int_a^b u dv \implies \\ [uv]_a^b - \int_a^b v du =   \int_a^b u dv.$$
My analysis says that the above is true but would request if anybody could help me with a better understanding. Or is my understanding of definite integral flawed?

Comment: Yes, providing of course the integrands are defined on $[a, b]$ then your assumption is correct.

Comment: Google "integration by parts"

Comment: It is a proof (not that rigorous) of the integration by parts

Comment: @ Bacon My question was more related to the definite integral than the indefinite one which is given in any standard book on calculus